# Bullet list-type:none not working

Tags: html, html-lists

The bullet points at www.example.com are in the form of guillemets (angle quotes ») instead of the regular black circles. Now, I specifically wanted the angle quotes on the sidebar, so that's working, but I don't want them on the body content of the page...

Can you figure out why the bullets are still acting like they're in the sidebar and how can I make them normal? I've tried list-type:none already...

Comment: You may have set that style to the "body" css selector and not just the sidebar.

Comment: Can you post the CSS that styles your lists?

Comment: @JSW189 Posted below by Elisa...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they are not set with `list-style-type` (that doesn't allow quotes) but with [generated content](http://blog.gabrieleromanato.com/2012/02/css-generated-content-tutorial/)

Just remove `.entry ul li:before,` from the declaration

```
.entry ul li:before, #sidebar ul ul li:before {
    content: "» ";
}
```

at line 373 of `style.css`

If you want bullets in the content, edit line 369 of `style.css` this way:

```
html > body .entry li {
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin: 7px 0 8px 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

If you want you can adjust margin and padding to fit to your needs

Comment: Hi Elisa; when I remove that, it removes the bullet points entirely, acute angles or otherwise.

Comment: So you want quotes in the sidebar and bullets in the content?

Comment: Exactly. Also, what exactly is generated content? I didn't code the whole website so... I'm assuming that that's nothing bad and it's just another type of code, right?

Comment: I've edited my answer, now it should work as you desire. For an explanation about css generated content, just follow the link I put in the answer